# Why does Bash wrap this output line onto itself?

Tags: bash

I've got a file that holds a token:

```
$ cat .token
token="35aaac83-cd67-5ced-a3b5-00c388f725c5"
```

I am trying to use this file inside a Bash function:

```
func() {

    . .token

    local payload='{                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",                                                                                                                                                                               
        "method": "listFile",                                                                                                                                                                           
        "params": [ "'"$token"'", "/" ],                                                                                                                                                                
        "id": 1                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }'    

    echo "$payload"
}
```

When I run this function, the output is:

```
{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "listFile",
", "/" ],params": [ "35aaac83-cd67-5ced-a3b5-00c388f725c5
        "id": 1
    }
```

As you can see, the line with `params` gets wrapped onto itself. I can't figure out why. I've been able to ascertain this has something to do with the `.` sourcing of the `$token`: when I hardwire `$token`, everything works fine. What's that matter here?

Comment: `hexdump` the file and look for stray `\r`

Comment: @thrig Heh, indeed the ending chars are `0d0a`. I did this, but somehow missed this on the first time around. Thank you. Please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @thrig: if you could explain why the `CRLF` causes a wrap though...

Comment: The `\r` means "go back to the start of the line", which will then cause it to overwrite anything else on that line.  I bet there is only a `\r` in `$token` and the `\n` is from somewhere else

Comment: @EricRenouf yes, totally. thank you!